# Weird app behaviour when i launch iPhone Retina 64 bit simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have 2 issues, that i found launching my app on 64bit simulator. Firstly, take a look at this 2 screenshots:

[image]

[image]

First screenshot was made on iPhone simulator 4 (iPhone simulator 3.5 work good as well). Second was made launching app on iPhone 4 Retina 64 bit simulator. There is represented rectangle with UIView and UICollectionView. Why this is not work on 64 bit simulator? Is there bug in Xcode or i made mistake in code? Also, my methods that include UIGestureRecognizer work bad. There it is:

```
-(void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    NSLog(@"Swipe received.");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

    self.myCollectionView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    if (IS_IPHONE_5){
        NSLog(@" its iphone 5");
    }
}

-(void)handleSwipeDown:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    NSLog(@"Swipe received.");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

    self.myCollectionView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 152, 320, 480);

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    if (IS_IPHONE_5){
        NSLog(@" its iphone 5");
    }
}

-(void)swipeUp{

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer;

    recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
    [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}

-(void)swipeDown{

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer;

    recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeDown:)];
    [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown)];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}
```

When it launched on iPhone 3,5 or iPhone 4 swipes work very well, but on 64 bit it hardly to do swipe up, and then i could not swipe down. It actually do swipe cells itself, not moving frame like it should.

Is there bug with Xcode? Will my app work fine in iPhone 5S on release?

Any advice would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Does your code build without warnings and errors?

Comment: There is a lot of "yellow" errors like - Prototype collection view cells must have reuse identifiers, others just about depreciated methods (in other classes, not this one) or (null): Directory not found for option '-F/Users/apple/Desktop'. App work perfectly, i just mention that is have issues launched on 64 bit simulator.

Comment: Well… your app does not work perfectly, as you can see. Please don't ignore warnings. Post a screenshot of all your warnings.

Comment: it may not the reason of your problem, but I (and the Apple too) encourage you to use _block-based_ animations since iOS4.

Comment: Are you doing any kind of transform (i.e rotation) on your collection view or cells?

Answer (score 1):

It must be something wrong over here on this line

self.myCollectionView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 152, 320, 480);

Where you set frame, ..its 480 so the collectionView must be getting distorted, Instead use

self.myCollectionView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 152, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

and then try..to run

Comment: Unfortunnately, thats not work. And what about that strange colour for UICollectionView?..

Answer (score 0):

For all who interested in solution that i found, please read following:

For colour, i checked CollectionView colour in storyboard, that was set to light blue (you can see it in second screen). Then, i disable ScrollingEnabled and Bounces Zoom in storyboard, after that, my swipe gesture recognisers again started to work as it should. Then, i set colour programmatically;

```
//That is method from category i add. It just simplify setting RGB colour for UIColor class
self.myCollectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithR:100 G:100 B:100 A:1];
```

There is result:
[image]

You may notice, that there is no more black borders in cells. Well, i can live with it, as long as i have custom images for every cell.

I still not understand, why there is difference in behaviour of my app for 64 bit devices (that include iPad 64 bit simulator too). I hope Apple will fix it in next version of Xcode.